# Generating very large XML file with Linq-to-XML and Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to do a dump to XML of a very large database (many gigabytes). I'm using Linq-to-SQL to get the data out of the database and Linq-to-XML to generate XML. I'm using `XStreamingElement` to keep memory use low. The job still allocates all available memory, however, before keeling over without having written any XML. The structure looks like this:

```
var foo =
    new XStreamingElement("contracts",
       <LinqtoSQL which fetches data>.Select(d =>
    new XElement("contract",
        ... generate attributes etc...
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("contracts.xml"))
{
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        foo.WriteTo(xw);
    }
}
```

I've also tried saving with:

```
foo.Save("contracts.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

...to no avail.

Any clues?

Comment: How about serialising as sql? it would be big but at least you could read it sequentially...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, "solved" the problem by chunking my data into sets of 10,000 items and writing them to separate XML files. Will ponder other data exchange format and buy a larger server.

I would still be mighty interesting if someone had figured out how to properly take advantage of `XStreamingElement`.

Comment: I think `XStreamingElement` is not a problem. Are you trying to get all the data from SQL Server using single LINQ to SQL query? If so, the memory still has to be allocated to handle results of LINQ to SQL query. I would try fetching data from DB in smaller chunks, e.g. using `Skip`/`Take` combinations, like if you'd try to make a paging system.

Answer (score 1):

How complex is the data? I'm not overly familiar with `XStreamingElement`, but I wonder if you might have more joy using `XmlWriter` directly? Especially for like data in a loop, it can be used pretty easily.

I would, however, have concerns over xml as the choice for this data. Is this s requirement? Or simply a convenient available format? In particular, it can be hard to **parse** that size of xml conveniently, as you'd have to use `XmlReader` (which is harder to get right than `XmlWriter`).

If you *can* use other formats, I'd advise it... a few leap to mind, but I won't babble on unless you mention that you'd be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you only need one clue for that: don't do it. :-)

XML is not an adequate format for database dumps because it does not handle large amounts of data well.

All databases have some sort of "dump" utility to export their data in a format that can then be read into another database - that would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm sure there is a valid reason friism is trying to dump to XML.

Comment: There is never a *good* reason to try and dump 1 gig of database data to what would end up as 20 gig of XML. :-)

Comment: It's not a pure dump, only some columns are included and there's a bit of processing involved. The reason I'm doing this, is because I want to make the data avilable to others who don't use SQL Server (right now, it will be imported into MySQL). I acknowledge your point however, it's a good one. With compression, the overhead should not be disastrous though.

Comment: Every database can export to, and import from flat data files at blazing speeds (several 100k records in a few seconds). Compressed XML still has to be un-compressed to process and will be painfully slow compared to a flat file load - how many related tables / records are you wanting to export?

Comment: There are more than 100.000 rows ("contracts") and each contract may have dozens of related rows ("contract winners", etc). Is there a good, cross-platform flat-file format with good tooling? If so, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Flat files are basically the "lowest common denominator".  All databases have a way to export / import them but it's specific to the db.  SQL Server has bcp.exe or sqlcmd.exe for exporting, MySQL has mysql_import for importing - and the importer has to create the table to hold it first.